# Radar search does not bring back all data - GOOGLE PLACES API

Tags: google-places-api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/xml?location=42.9825,-81.254&radius=15000&sensor=false&key=KEY&types=pharmacy

Does not seem to bring back anything other than geometry, reference and id, none of the other info is available, this use to work, did something happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Radar Search Requests have always only provided this limited set of data per place.  From the current [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#RadarSearchRequests):

> The search response will include up to 200 Places, identified only by their geographic coordinates and Place reference.

Comment: I must have been drunk then but i was sure it had all the details, thank you for the info.

Comment: And how to get all data for all found places? Send 200 requests for all 200 places?